# Update UWP application like ClickOnce

Tags: c#, uwp, clickonce

**By Panagiotis D. Satos, Arta - Greece**

**1.** Create a C# Console Application (Project Name: Updater).

Inside the Main method write the following code block:

**Console.Write("Update Applications...");**

**Excel();**

```
    private static void Excel()
    {            
        string l_strFileName = "\\\\192.168.1.3\\update\\Updater\\Updater.xls";
        String l_strCon = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + l_strFileName + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No'";
        OleDbConnection l_oleDBcon = new OleDbConnection(l_strCon);
        l_oleDBcon.Open();
        DataTable dt = l_oleDBcon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        String[] l_strExcelSheetsNames = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            l_strExcelSheetsNames[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            i++;
        }
        OleDbCommand l_oleDBcommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + l_strExcelSheetsNames[0] + "]", l_oleDBcon);
        OleDbDataAdapter l_loeDBadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        l_loeDBadapter.SelectCommand = l_oleDBcommand;
        DataSet l_ds = new DataSet();
        l_loeDBadapter.Fill(l_ds);
        ArrayList l_listPaths = new ArrayList();
        string l_strPath;
        for (i = 0; i <= l_ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            l_strPath = l_ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            if (l_strPath.Equals(""))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                l_listPaths.Add(l_strPath);
            }
        }
        l_oleDBcon.Close();
        if (l_listPaths.Count > 0)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < l_listPaths.Count; i++)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(l_listPaths[i].ToString());
            }                
        }                     
    }
```

**2.** Add the Console Application (**Updater.exe**) at network path (folder), which is the same path from which our Applications was installed to our LAN computers. For example:

\\192.168.1.3\update\Updater\

**3.** At the same path, add also an excel file (**Updater.xls**).
There, you can add the paths of new versions of your applications. For example, these are the paths of new verions of two applications:

\\192.168.1.3\update\Updater\UWP\AppPackages\UWP_1.0.8.0_Debug_Test\UWP_1.0.8.0_x86_x64_arm_Debug.appxbundle

\\192.168.1.3\update\Updater\AppUpdate\AppPackages\AppUpdate_1.0.3.0_Debug_Test\AppUpdate_1.0.3.0_x86_x64_arm_Debug.appxbundle

**4.** Create a shortcup of Updater.exe (\\192.168.1.3\update\Updater\Updater.exe) in startup folder (Open folder: press WinKey + R (Run...), write: shell:startup, press Enter key) of each LAN computer.

[Open starup folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdgqm.png)

**5.** Add server path \\192.168.1.3 at Intranet Settings

[Intranet settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhDFV.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It isn't a question. It just an implementation. I share it with the community, because UWP haven't auto update functionality (like WPF ClickOnce).